# Marginal Probability Density Function of Joint Distribution

Tags: density-function, continuous-data, joint-distribution

I have this question regarding marginal probability density function of joint distribution. Following is the equation I have.

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2} y^2 & 0 \le x \le 2 \text{ and } 0 \le y \le 1 \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I am trying to find this probability:

$$P(X=3Y)$$

I have tried calculating $f_x(x)$ which equates to:

$$\int_0^\frac{x}{3} \frac{3}{2}y^2~dy$$
$$=\frac{3}{2} * \frac{\frac{x^3}{27}}{3}$$
$$=\frac{x^3}{54} \text{ if } 0 \le x \le 2$$

I am unsure whether what I did above is correct or not.
Furthermore, if it is calculating the probability of $X=3Y$, then why would I need to integrate this piecewise function?

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the square $(0,2)x(0,1)$. What is the Lebesgue measure of the line $\{(x,y);x-3y=0\}$?

Comment: @Xi'an, thank you for your comment. I haven't had a chance to learn Lebesgue measure yet in my area of study. After looking up and trying to understand the concept, it simply represents volume/area/length of a set. Therefore, the Lebesgue measure of the line would be simply an integration of that equation with boundaries you have set. However, I don't understand where the range of y went. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: what is the surface of a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you said about the nature of the problem (marginal distributions) I'm wondering if the problem actually asked for P(X | X = 3Y).

But if this is not the case The comment above applies. Consider a 1D example with PDF, f(x) = 1 for 0 < x < 1.  What is P(X = 0.5)?  How do you reach that answer?  It should involve integrating across the *entire* sample space.

Comment: Wouldn't $P(X=0.5) = P(0.5 \le X \le 0.5) = \text{ therefore, } 0$ ?

Comment: Yes.  Define g(x)=1 if x=0.5, and 0 otherwise.  This is called the indicator function for the set {0.5}.  You arrive at zero by integrating $f(x) \cdot g(x)$ over your sample space, which in my example is the unit interval.  What is g(x, y) in your example?  And what is the *entire* sample space in your example.

Comment: The above equations that I have written is all I have.

Comment: I disagree.  You also have your natural abilities of generalization and pattern matching. I asked you for P(X=0.5).  The set of solutions to the equation X = 0.5 is {0.5}.  So we computed the integral of f*g where g was the "indicator" function of that set, to get the probability.  In you example, what is the equation we want a set of solutions to, what is the indicator function g, and what is the integral of f*g.

Comment: I revisited my Calculus book and various Wikipedia pages before coming back. The indicator function I have is $g(x,y) = x-3y$ for the entire square region, x:{0,2} y:{0,1}. Then I will need to integrate f(x,y) * g(x,y) dydx. With regions given from original piecewise function.

Comment: Closer.  The indicator function is g(x,y) = 1 if x = 3y, 0 otherwise.  This is what an indicator function is.  It is 1 on a set and zero elsewhere.  Now compute the double integral.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the boundaries of the sample space. Where does "if x=3y go" for the indicator function go in the integrals?
Do I need to separate f(x,y) and g(x,y) in order to integrate with different regions? I tried modifying the original sample space domain by substituting x with 3y or y with 0.33x. Then with no surprise both outcomes were different.

Comment: You were correct about the domain.  Let's take this step.  Write a piece wise definition for f(x,y)*g(x,y)

Comment: My thought process was that because the indicator function is 0 when x is not 3*y, I changed the domain of the original sample space.
Here are two definitions that I thought were possible
$f(x,y) * g(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2} y^2 & 0 \le x \le 3, 0\le y\le1 \\ 0 & otherwise  \end{cases}$
$f(x,y) * g(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2} y^2 & 0 \le x \le 2, 0 \le y\le \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & otherwise  \end{cases}$

 

Come to think of it, because the first one exceeds the original sample space of f(x,y), now I think that the second one should be used.

Comment: You do not want to change the domain of the sample space.  The product is equal to 3/2 y^2 if 0 <= x <= 2 _and_ 0 <= y <= 1 _and_ x=3y, 0 otherwise.  So you should be picturing an thin curve floating over a sea of zero.  Compute the double integral of this function over the original domain [0,2]X[0,1].  And remember the simple example I gave you first.